# What is a square root?

Tags: arithmetic

If adding is the sum of two numbers, Subtraction is the removal of a number from another.

Multiplication is $x$ lots of $y$.

Division is splitting $x$ between $y$.

Powers are multiplying a value by itself.

What is a square root?

To be clear, I'm asking what function a square root actually performs?

I can't seem to come up with an answer without the concept of powers to refer to.

For example; how would you go about solving the square root of $121$ without prior knowledge that $11^2$ is $121$?

Is it as blind as testing every value up to or past an answer until we find a solution then doing bisection until we get a result?

Edit:
I think my question was still unclear, how could I perform a square root on a value without reverse engineering the question into a powers question. 
E.g. square root $123456$, you do not know if the root is whole or decimal.

Comment: NB your definitions of multiplication, division, and powers only make sense as stated for nonnegative integers. If you're happy to extend them all to rational values, then the square root map is just raising to the power $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: For that matter, how does one divide (i.e. "split $x$ between $y$") without "prior knowledge that $x = yz$"? "Is it as blind as testing every value up to or past an answer until we find a solution then doing bisection until we get a result?"

Comment: Take $x$ lots of $x$ till you get $y$ ... may be?

Comment: y is a number divide it by x you get x back

Comment: "E.g. square root 123456, you do not know if the root is whole or decimal."  - that should in general be fairly simple. By binary search (analogous to looking up a word in a dictionary) you should be able to find out quickly whether there is a natural number that is the square root of $123456$. And it's also a fact that whenever the square root of an natural number is not an integer, it must be irrational.

Comment: For the specific example, notice that $351^2 < 12346$, but $352^2 > 123456$.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can avoid falling back to powers, because the square root *is* shorthand for a particular power (specifically, one with an exponent of 0.5). So, it seems to me like the core of your question would be answered with an answer on how to calculate powers with real exponents. See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280901/calculating-powers

Comment: What's wrong with "reverse engineering"?  Subtraction and division are reverse engineering, aren't they?  So why is "the number which when squared is x" not acceptable?

Comment: I'm just gonna leave [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) here.  There's plenty of ways of computing square roots that don't require knowledge of squares.

Comment: The digits of 123456 add to 21 which is divisible by 3 but not by 9 so the 123456 is not the square of an integer because it i divisible by 3 but not by 9.

Comment: They used to teach how to compute square roots manually to arbitrary precision in grade school. It looks superficially like long division.

Comment: I changed the title to more accurately reflect what the question is asking.

Comment: @EricStucky: bad idea. This makes some of the answers nonsensiscal without future readers being able to know why. There should at least be a warning in the question body.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As I don't fully understand your question, I will divide my answer into three parts: ***the definition of a square root***, ***how to understand it***, and ***algorithms to calculate it.***

**DEFINITION OF A SQUARE ROOT**

To cite [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root),

> In mathematics, a square root of a number $a$ is a number $y$ such that
>    $y^2=a$, in other words a number $y$ whose square $(y \times y)$ is $a$. For example, $-4$ and $4$ are both square roots of $16$ because $(4)^2=(-4)^2=16$.
>
> Every non negative real number $a$ has a unique non-negative square root, called the **principal square root**, which is denoted by $\sqrt{a}$ where the $\sqrt{\square}$ sign is called a *radical sign* or a *radix*. For example, the principal square root of $9$ is $3$, denoted $\sqrt{9}=3$, because $3^2=9$ and $3$ is non negative. The term whose root is being considered is known as the *radicand*. The radicand is the number or expression underneath the radical sign, in this example $9$.

**HOW TO UNDERSTAND IT**

A way to approach this is thinking by reversal. What you do, someone can undo.

A $\color {blue}{\text{summation}}$ is the reverse of $\color {blue}{\text{subtraction}}$. Indeed,  $\color {blue}{\text{subtraction}}$ can 'undo' a $\color {blue}{\text{summation}}$, and $\color {blue}{\text{summation}}$ 'undoes' a $\color {blue}{\text{subtraction}}$.

$\color{green}{\text{Division}}$ is the reverse of $\color{green}{\text{multiplication}}$.  $\color{green}{\text{Division}}$ undoes a $\color{green}{\text{multiplication}}$,  $\color{green}{\text{Multiplication}}$ can be 'undone' with a $\color{green}{\text{division}}$.

Think of a $\color {orange}{\text{square root}}$ as a reversal of a $\color {orange}{\text{square}}$: you can "undo" a $\color {orange}{\text{square}}$ with a $\color {orange}{\text{square root}}$, and a $\color {orange}{\text{square}}$ can "undo" a $\color {orange}{\text{square root}}$. This may lead to some confusion, as $x^2$ is not invertible. To clarify, think of the square root of $16=4^2=(-4)^2$. A square root is not a function. Thus taking the square root of $16$ undoes the square, yielding two values- it becomes $4$, $-4$.

So to summarize $$\color {blue}{\text{summation}} \leftrightarrow \color {blue}{\text{subtraction}}$$$$\color{green}{\text{Division}} \leftrightarrow \color{green}{\text{multiplication}}$$ $$ \color {orange}{\text{square root}} \leftrightarrow \color {orange}{\text{square}}$$

**ALGORITHIMS TO FIND IT**

If you want to determine if it is whole or irrational, if a integer is between two squares, then it is decimal. In your example, since $351^2=123201<123456<123904=352^2$, it is irrational.

Of course, there are more clever arguments. For example, if $3$ divides $n$ but $n$ is not divisible by $9$, this implies $n$ is not a square. This is true in case of $n=123456$. Other examples include $$n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow n \quad \text{is not a square}$$ $$n \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5 \Rightarrow n \quad \text{is not a square}$$ But note these methods are not always easy-and sometimes require luck.

A operation for finding (or approximating) square roots exists, not to different from long division. A simple one can be seen [here](http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/square-root-algorithm.php).

Of course, the quickest way to approximate it is using the sequence {$x_{n}$} which is defined as follows.

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{c}{x_{n}})$$

It is not to hard to see that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x_{n}=\sqrt{c}$. This sequence actually converges pretty quickly, so this is useful, which is equivalent to [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) in $x^2-N$.

There are, of course, other algorithims to calculate the square root. And there are some rather exclusive ones as well. For example, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}}+\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}}=\sqrt{5}$$
Where $F_{n}$ is the [Fibonacci Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). But not converge quite as quickly as the one above.

*More discussion on the* [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278290/what-exactly-is-a-square-root?rq=1), *and the* [algorithims](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90435/how-can-i-find-the-square-root-using-pen-and-paper/90438#90438) *can be* *found in the links provided*.

Comment: It is not quite true that a square root is the undoing of the operation of squaring.  The reason is that squaring is not an invertible function.  (-5)^2 = 25 but the square root of 25 is +5.

Comment: @DavidC Good point. Does my edit fix matters? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I hate when MathJax is used to render normal text.

Comment: @DavidC but you are wrong that the square root of $25$ is $5$-that is incorrect. It is both $5$ and $-5$.

Comment: @kamil09875 Could you present to me a better way to color these letters? I think that it helps it stand out more. Some users seems to have a better understanding when the result it is visual.

Comment: @MXYMXY well yes, but one should consider using other visual effects than colors (see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/on-the-use-of-color-in-equations) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-so-question-editor)). MathJax should be used just for math.

Comment: @kamil09875 Thanks. Would you like to suggest any? I'm lost. The links you provided seem to suggest the  \color is overused, but does not provide a alternative solution for normal text.

Comment: @MXYMXY when writing answers I always try to make them hierarchical and emphasize important parts using italics/bold font when needed (bold font seem to be overused too). In most cases colors are not useful. In your case I would emphasize only first occurrences of colored words, that's enough IMO.

Comment: @kamil09875 I will take it in to consideration. However, I am busy right now, and I hope you will not be offended by my lack of edits for the next $16$ hours or so.

Comment: Or 16, since this isn't math.

Comment: @MXYMXY . After typing for an hour here and then going to Facebook , I find myself putting dollar signs and / on things.:)

Comment: Bear in mind that about 5-10% of the male population is colorblind to one degree or another. If you must use colors, blue is pretty safe, red not quite so and that bown color you use is a really poor choice.

Comment: @MSYMXY,  If you take the view that the square root is a function (or an operation), as I do, then there can only be a single element from the co-domain for any given element of the domain. (Expressed differently, there can only be one output for any input.) Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidC Unless I am mistaken, is the square root of $16$ not both $4$ and $-4$? I thought that square root did not necessarily mean $\sqrt{x}$, which can only take the value of positive real numbers if they are not imaginary.

Comment: @RickDecker Is this better?

Comment: @DavidC Indeed, you are talking about the Principal square root, not the square root itself.

Comment: @DavidC  To clarify, I cited more text from wikipedia.

Comment: Just because it doesn’t seem to be intentional: your statements about the reversability of division/multiplication and square roots/squares are backwards, as it were. With summation/subtraction, you get it right, saying that summation can undo subtraction and vice versa; with the other two, you accidentally structure the sentences so that the agent and the patient switch places—you end up saying that “division/square roots can undo multiplication/squares, and division/square roots and undo multiplications/squares”, i.e., saying the same thing twice.

Comment: MXYMXY, the definition from Wikipedia is fine.  Square root is a relation but it's not a function, that is, it is not a functional relation.  That's why it cannot be described as the undoing of squaring. Squaring is a function but it is not invertible. (I think you mean inverting when you talk about reversing.)  This doesn't invalidate your code.  It merely suggests more caution in the description of taking the square root.

Comment: “Another rather famous one is using Newton's Method …” which, for this function, is exactly the method just described: replace $x$ with $x+\frac{N-x^2}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{N}{x}+x)$.

Comment: I think there is an analog to the case of the relation of raising a number to a power not being an invertible function when the power is even: The relation of multiplying by a number is not an invertible function when the number is $0$. For someone who understands "division is the reverse of multiplication, **except when multiplying by zero**", writing that "the positive square root is the reverse of squaring **except when the radicand is negative**" would probably make sense.

Comment: I prefer to write Newton's method in this case as $$x_{n+1}=\frac{c+(x_n)^2}{2x_n}$$

Answer (score 17):

I think you're confusing the *definition* of a square root with the *algorithm* needed to compute it. In mathematics, there are many concepts that we can define, but where it may be hard to actually find some object satisfying the property.

*A* square root of a number $n$ is defined as any number $x$ that satifies this property: $$x^2 = n.$$

For example, we can verify that $2$ and $-2$ are square roots of $4$.

Often we talk about *the* square root, which is an abbreviation for the term *principal square root*. By that we mean the simple convention that $\sqrt{4} = 2$ (and not $-2$). But that is just a convention.

Actually *finding* a square root is more complex. Many algorithms will use somewhat higher mathematics. But the gist of it is: take a number $a$ whose square is less than $n$ and another number $b$ whose square is bigger than $n$ and then you know that the square root of $n$ must be between those two. Repeat until you have enough accuracy as needed (you will rarely ever be *done*, since most square roots are irrational).

Comment: In other words, yes, it’s basically blind-testing until you get there. (Right?)

Comment: It's not so much "blind testing" as using an algorithm that *is guaranteed* to get you closer and closer to the answer the more often you apply it. But in essence, it is some sort of "advanced guesswork"; only, you can be clever about it, see MXYMXY's answer for details.

Answer (score 11):

You are asking "Is it as blind as testing every value up to or past an answer until we find a solution then doing bisection until we get a result?", "How could I perform a square root on a value without reverse engineering the question into a powers question?"

A very similar situation occurs with division, which is defined by reference to multiplication. How do I known if $\dfrac{123456}{643}$ is whole or decimal ? There's nothing more mysterious about [square] roots.

As there are numerical algorithms that allow you to perform divisions, there are some for roots. You can also resort to logarithms/antilogarithms.

And, yes, extracting a root requires to somehow solve a power equation, in the same sense that performing a division requires to solve a multiplicative equation.

Answer (score 10):

If you think at the square power $l^2$ as the area of the square of side $l$, than the square root is to find the side of a square of given area. This seams the more intuitive interpretation of the square root for positive real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

To answer in the same fashion you asked:

To square a number is to convert a line into a square--for instance a line of 10 blocks made "Square" will create a square of 100 blocks.

To take a "Square" of 25 blocks and reduce it to a line would give you 5 blocks.

There are many better answers here, but I didn't see one explaining it in the same way you asked..

Edit: I just realized I could have said it more clearly with better wording:

Squaring is the operation used to find the area of a square from the length of a side.

Square root is finding the length of a side from the area of a square.

This is why we use the name "Square".

Answer (score 2):

I like This way, which is a cute tool for mental square roots (a bit approximate but it may works for daily use).

Call $N$ the number you have to root and think about the nearest perfect square $s^2$. Then you can always write

$$N = s^2 \pm q$$

There is the approximation:

$$\sqrt{N} = \sqrt{s^2 \pm q} \approx s \pm \frac{q}{2s}$$

**Example**

Suppose we want to find an approximation of the square root of $87$ (which is $9.3274..$). Then the nearest perfect square could be $81$:

$$\sqrt{87} = \sqrt{81 + 6} \approx 9 + \frac{6}{18} = 9 + \frac{1}{3} = 9.3333333...$$

On the same way on could take $100$ as the nearest perfect square:

$$\sqrt{87} = \sqrt{100 - 13} \approx 10 - \frac{13}{20} = 10 - 0.65 = 9.35$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but I offer up the following two thoughts in case they help. Considering the positive integer x:

1) Add up odd numbers until the sum is greater than or equal to x. Let n be the number of addends (the number of odd numbers you summed). If you hit x exactly, then the square root is n. If you overshot, then the square root is between n and n-1. This is sort of a computational approach.

2) If you want to make a square with area x, then square roots tell you how long the sides need to be. This is sort of a functional approach.

My guess is that you want to explain the concept to someone who isn't particularly inclined to math so I'm not being very formal. Again, I hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

You need square root of x.
What you are doing can be explained in a simple way.Say you have x kg of wheat and you are breaking this into n groups of n kg each.Now we have n groups of n kg implying ${n}^{2} $ kg which is equal to x kg. Hence, we find square root of x is n.So, I would say that square root would be to divide the number x in n equal parts such that each group has value n.This is a relatively simple and qualitative argument.Hope this helps you in understanding.